# Jquery append input element and send data from that input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple HTML code:

```
<div id="new_gallery">
    <p id="add_gallery">Add new gallery</p>
</div>
```

and jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $("#add_gallery").click(function() {
        $("#new_gallery").append('<input name"new_gallery" /><a href="#" id="create_new_gallery">Add</a>');
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $("#create_new_gallery").on('click', function(){
        alert('1'); 
    });
</script>
```

First function is working, but second one is not. I need to create new `input` element, send data via ajax, and then delete the `input` element and append a `p` element once again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the second statement runs, the element `#create_new_gallery` does not exist yet so it does nothing.

You can do the binding to the click event after you created the element for instance, this ensures the element exists in the DOM:

```
$("#add_gallery").click(function() {
    $("#new_gallery").append('<input name="new_gallery" /><a href="#" id="create_new_gallery">Add</a>');
    $(this).remove();
    $("#create_new_gallery").on('click', function() {
        alert('1');
    });
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/WSHE2/)**

---

Here is a little bit more optimized version. It's a bit non-sense to append an element and have to re-query for it (event though querying by id is the fastest method. Besides, it's best to use the chaining capabilities of jQuery afterall:

```
$("#add_gallery").click(function() {
    var $gallery = $("#new_gallery");

    $('<input name="new_gallery" />').appendTo($gallery);
    $('<a href="#" id="create_new_gallery">Add</a>')
        .on('click', function() {
            alert('1');
        })
        .appendTo($gallery);

    $(this).remove();
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/a7GGJ/)**

Comment: A pity that `create_new_gallery` has to be created and selected in the same part of the code. Have a look to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`#create_new_gallery` doesn't exist when you bind its click event.

Here is what your code should look like:

```
$("#add_gallery").click(function() {
  var newG = $("#new_gallery");
  $('<input name"new_gallery" />').appendTo(newG);
  $('<a href="#" id="create_new_gallery">Add</a>').appendTo(newG).on('click',
    function() {
      alert('1');
    });

  $(this).remove();
});
```

Notice that getting `$("#new_gallery")` into a variable avoid to look for it twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add_gallery").click(function() {
        $("#new_gallery").append('<input name"new_gallery" /><a href="#" id="create_new_gallery">Add</a>');
        $(this).remove();
        $("#create_new_gallery").on('click', function(){
           alert('1'); 
        });
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/39E4s/2/
​

Answer (score -1):

Try `live` to handle the events fired for elements added after the page has loaded.

```
$("#create_new_gallery").live('click', function(){
   alert('1'); 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `live()` is deprecated. Use `delegate()` or `on()` instead.